# Repeating status from one record to the next

Tags: powerbi, dax

All,
I’m still learning DAX and got this task; I’m trying to repeat the status value from 1 record to the next.  YEC Comments is a separate SharePoint list and uses Power App and collects Project, DTE/Tm, Status and Comments.

1. When there’s no status, by default Status = ‘Not Closed’
2. The status will repeat itself to the next record until the next status change.
3. There are multiple projects with the same date/time
4. Project and DTETm are the join fields between the two list.
   Note:  I do not have pro license.

[image]

I’m trying to get the status to repeat itself so it’ll look like below.
[image]

Comments:

```
Project,DteTm,Comments,Status,Title
Proj 1,9/28/2023 9:30,once upon a time,Closed,
Proj 2,9/28/2023 9:30,sleepy,Not Closed,
Proj 2,10/1/2023 0:45,test,Closed,
Proj 3,9/28/2023 9:30,test,Closed,
Proj 3,9/30/2023 22:00,test,Closed,
Proj 3,9/30/2023 17:00,test,Minor Issues,
Proj 3,9/29/2023 9:30,test,Not Closed,
Proj 3,9/30/2023 23:00,test,Not Closed,
Proj 3,10/1/2023 0:45,tst,Closed,
```

Data:

```
Project,DTETm,Sales,Exp
Proj 1,9/27/2023 9:00,$273 ,$538.09 
Proj 1,9/28/2023 9:30,$273 ,$540.01 
Proj 1,9/28/2023 13:00,$273 ,$540.72 
Proj 1,9/28/2023 16:00,$273 ,$540.99 
Proj 1,9/29/2023 8:00,$273 ,$541.41 
Proj 1,9/29/2023 9:30,$273 ,$541.45 
Proj 1,9/29/2023 13:00,$273 ,$541.47 
Proj 1,9/29/2023 16:00,$273 ,$541.55 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 9:30,$273 ,$541.55 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 13:00,$273 ,$541.55 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 15:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 16:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 17:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 18:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 19:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 20:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 21:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 22:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,9/30/2023 23:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,10/1/2023 0:15,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,10/1/2023 0:45,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,10/2/2023 16:00,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,10/3/2023 10:30,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 1,10/10/2023 11:30,$273 ,$541.61 
Proj 2,9/27/2023 9:00,$204 ,$223.22 
Proj 2,9/28/2023 9:30,$204 ,$224.37 
Proj 2,9/28/2023 13:00,$204 ,$226.40 
Proj 2,9/28/2023 16:00,$204 ,$226.40 
Proj 2,9/29/2023 8:00,$204 ,$226.62 
Proj 2,9/29/2023 9:30,$204 ,$226.63 
Proj 2,9/29/2023 13:00,$204 ,$226.65 
Proj 2,9/29/2023 16:00,$204 ,$226.99 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 9:30,$204 ,$227.77 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 13:00,$204 ,$227.78 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 15:00,$204 ,$227.79 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 16:00,$204 ,$227.79 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 17:00,$204 ,$228.02 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 18:00,$204 ,$228.02 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 19:00,$204 ,$228.05 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 20:00,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 21:00,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 22:00,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,9/30/2023 23:00,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,10/1/2023 0:15,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,10/1/2023 0:45,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,10/2/2023 16:00,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,10/3/2023 10:30,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 2,10/10/2023 11:30,$204 ,$228.08 
Proj 3,9/30/2023 22:00,"$7,249 ","$13,229.37 "
Proj 3,9/30/2023 23:00,"$7,249 ","$13,229.45 "
Proj 3,10/1/2023 0:15,"$7,249 ","$13,229.45 "
Proj 3,10/1/2023 0:45,"$7,249 ","$13,229.45 "
Proj 3,10/2/2023 16:00,"$7,249 ","$13,231.51 "
Proj 3,10/3/2023 10:30,"$7,249 ","$13,231.51 "
Proj 3,10/10/2023 11:30,"$7,249 ","$13,231.51 "
```

Comment: Can you provide your dataset ?

Comment: Was going to provide the Power BI file, but couldn't figure out how to attach the file.  So, I just added the raw data.

Comment: You can put it on Google Drive/OneDrive for example.

Comment: I don't use any online storage/never set 1 up

Comment: Ok at least try to provide a clear info about your dataset. Is it one table ? the data about the comments that you provided is a seperate table?

Comment: the data are 2 separate table.  1 is called comments, other called main (primary). Both table are join by DteTM column.  When the data is pulled into a table view you get the first image (blanks in the status column).  The second picture is the desired outcome.   The other 2 are csv extract.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is fairly simple,

1. Data Table:   create key field (project, DteTm)
2. Comments Table:   create key field (Project, DteTm)
3. On model view, create a join between the two tables
4. Create base comment table, (project, DteTm, status, key)
5. set the status default
6. Append the new table to the comments
7. Add the comments fields data table
8. Sort key ascending
9. Replicate down